# How to Set FK enforcement equal false In .net core 3.1 when UseSqlite

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, .net-core-3.1

In .net core version 2.0 I use `serviceCollection.AddDbContextPool<StandardDBContext>(o => o.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + connectionDb, x => x.SuppressForeignKeyEnforcement()));` to set 
FK enforcement equal false

'SuppressForeignKeyEnforcement' not found in .net core version 3.1, FK enforcement is switched on by default as I read in  [Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes)

How can I do the same in .net core 3.1, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pure Sqlite way, independent of any language's bindings to the library and its particular quirks, is to execute a [`PRAGMA foreign_keys`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) command after opening a database.

To disable foreign key enforcement:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = off
```

To turn them on:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on
```